# SQL whats faster for select: bitwise "and" or joins with bigint

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have MS SQL 2012 DB with table for documents.

In application there are `users`.

- `users` can be `document managers`.
- one `user` can be `manager` for many `documents`
- one `document` can have many `managers`.

There is limit 50 user for app.

I was wondering what will be te best way(or fastest) to search `document` that `manager` is some user(or few users).

1) One table for document and additional for document manager objects. then search like

```
select from document dk 
join documentmanager dm on dm.dokid=dk.id and dm.userlogin='xxx'
```

or

2) do not use additional table for manager object, instead bind each user managernumber from 1 to 50 then when serach use :

```
SELECT * FROM documents where (managers & CAST(manager AS BIGINT) <> 0)
```

where manager is 2^managernumber .

Second one seem to be faster and simplier and not required that additional table so also requires less space. But i dont know if i use indexes on that additional table that maybe it will be faster then 2) . Of course there is limitation to 63 users but let say its not important.

Answer (score 1):

The first idea is how a relational database is typically designed.  There is a reason -- it is the better design for a database.

You say the limit on the number of users does not matter you don't need more than 63.  In my opinion if you have less than 63 of anything you don't need a database.  You can load it in from any file and store all the information in memory.  **If size and scalability don't matter then don't even use a database.**

In every other case use the standard relational design that has been proven robust over many years.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell which one would be faster, at least when the number of records is small. The second approach has a simpler query, but it can't make use of any indexes as it has to calculate the value of the expression for each document.

The second approach may seem easier, but it's actually quite unconventional. Looking at the table design of the first approach anyone with a bit of database experience can immediately tell how it's supposed to work. Anyone looking at the second approach needs to examine the query to figure out what the "magic" numbers in the table is supposed to mean.

Even if the number of users is limited so that the second approach would be usable, the number of documents is likely to grow over time. As the query in the second approach has to examine every document it will get slower when the number of documents grow. The query in the first approach on the other hand can make use of indexes, so the execution time is mostly depending on the number of records returned, not so much on the number of records in the tables. It can easily handle tables with upwards of millions of records before you would even notice any difference in performance.

Comment: Thanks. I thought so, but need to get such clarification from more eperienced users :)

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to say, with less snark.  I still think no DB is needed. :)